# How to record a website with video?

Tags: loadrunner

I mean what protocol we need to use and what are recording options we have to use when we want record a website with video. I also want play the video while recording. And what are the steps need to take while replaying the script?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand architecturally how the video is being delivered.  Is is unicast, multicast, or simply a file download where the video file (mp4, etc....) may start playing before the video is finished downloading.

With the streaming former, the you need to look at items such as Mean Opinion Score for streaming quality. The choice of unicast or Multicast will determine your load on your server and your network with wide variations between the two.  With the file download model, essentially you just need to worry about whether the download of the file happens within the length of the video.